# How to use future builder in slivers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I want to display data from the api in the slivers using future builder with grid layouts. I tried but i could not do that.
Here is the code

```
 slivers: [
 SliverGrid(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                  child: Text('grid item $index'),
                );
              },
              childCount: 10,
            ),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 15,
              crossAxisSpacing: 15,
              childAspectRatio: 2.0,
            ),
          )
        ],
```

I tried this way. but child count is the problem

```
  SliverGrid(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: getProducts(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Hello',
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              childCount: 10,
            ),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 15,
              crossAxisSpacing: 15,
              childAspectRatio: 2.0,
            ),
          )
```

Comment: *where* is the futurebuilder???

Comment: I want to use. How can i use this ?? I want to display data from the api .

Comment: You can put the future builder in the delegate (*i.e.* `return FutureBuilder(..` instead of just `return Container(..`), assuming you know how to use a FutureBuilder. If you don't know how to use a FutureBuilder, then it's not a question related to `SilverGrid` at all.

Comment: A usual way is to (in the builder) first check `snapshot.hasData`, if false, return some kind of progress-indicator (like a circle or anything). If true, then `snapshot.data` contains the thing from your `Future`, whatever that is.

Comment: Okay. but what about child count ? HOw can i pass the length ?

Comment: If you need `childCount` to depend on the future, then put `FutureBuilder` an ancestor of your silvers.

Comment: How sir. please give me some code snippet.

Comment: Put FutureBuilder *outside* the `SilverGrid`. It's not too hard, considering you managed to follow my first advice and put it in the delegate.

Comment: I am working on a e commerce app layout. at top i have a slider, then horizontal categories list and then have vertical products grid. so how can i wrap this future builder with ```customescroll view widget```

Answer (score 0):

get that future and build the delegate inside your FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
       future:YourApi(),
       builder:(_,snap){
         if(snap.hasData){
         //get your data , if its json, decode and make it into a class
         List<T> data = snap.data .......
         return ....(
           slivers:[
            SliverGrid(
              ......
              ,childCount: data.lenght
            )
          ]
        )
      } else {}
     }
    )
```

Comment: But sir, future builder is not working inside the ```slivers : [ FutureBuilder()]```

Comment: i am not put in on slivers[], may i get your parent widget code?

Comment: i assume you use `CustomScrollView`, put future builder as parent

Comment: ```Scaffolt=>CustomScrollView => slivers[]```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `FutureBuilder` inside `slivers`. just make sure the return widget is needed to be a sliver widget on every case.

```dart
body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
      /// create a future variable on state class
      future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2))
          .then((value) => List.generate(11, (i) => i)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return SliverGrid(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                childCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                (context, index) => Container(
                  child: Text("${snapshot.data?[index]}"),
                ),
              ),
              gridDelegate:
                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2));
        }
        return const SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    )
  ],
),
```